# How does one create a function containing os.system in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, os.system

I'm in python 3 and on debian

I would like to have a function that uses os.system. For simplicity's sake something along the lines of:

```
def notxt():
       command = "rm *.txt"
       os.system(command)
notxt()
```

but when I run the script, it hangs without carrying out the command. Is there a way around this or am I approaching it incorrectly?

Comment: I left it running for about 5 minutes and it still remained hanging. I have noticed it seems to carry out the command when I ctrl-c in the terminal, maybe I need to put a break after the command or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use subproccess here then use run. Like this

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["rm", "1.txt"])
```

You might to find another bash command to delete all txt files

Here is the docs:

[Python3 Docs for Subproccess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)